# What's 'void' on NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I defined a NSArray in a header file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *ages;
```

In my implementation I want to set this variable like this:

```
ages = [self setAges:[ageValues allKeys]];
```

'ageValues' is a NSDictionary. So what I do is just setting the array of keys to my self-defíned array. Strange enough, I get the following error message:

Asssigning to 'NS Array *' from incompatible type 'void'

But where can I find something void here? In my opionion I am just setting another array ([ageValues allKeys) to my own array and I can't find anything void???

Comment: [self setAges:[ageValues allKeys]]; should be enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setAges:` method is a method that returns `void`, in other words: it returns *nothing* (not even `nil` or something; it literally is not returning anything). Now you cannot assign "nothing" to a variable.

That being said, your code wants to do the same thing twice. All you want to do is simply:

```
self.ages = [ageValues allKeys];
```

or:

```
[self setAges:[ageValues allKeys]];
```

They do exactly the same, but use different syntax (the compiler transforms the first into the second).

Comment: Aaargh! How could I be that blind? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

*setAges* is a **void** method since it's a setter. As such, it returns void and you're then trying to assign it to your *ages* member. All you need to do is call *setAges*.

```
[ self setAges:[ ageValues allKeys ] ];
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.ages = [ageValues allKeys];`
or
`ages = [[ageValues allKeys] retain];`

Answer (score 1):

```
[self setAges:[ageValues allKeys]]; returns void.
```

If you have synthesized your `ages` property in your `.m` like so:

```
@synthesize ages;
```

The setter is automatically generated for you, so all you need to do is

```
self.ages = [ageValues allKeys];
```